# Android app. using Mysql DB

Tags: android

I;m new in Android.
please give me the steps for connecting mysql database in android.
i have tried many examples.

Comment: I sugguset you to use SQLite3 database on Android http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: can i insert or see data on android app.which is install on android mobile if i use SQLite3....i want to make a app.which will show the some reports in android mobile from anywhere....so SQLite3 will be ok..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: I have tried this one....this statement not get executed..      HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);